# What prerequisite knowledge I need to solve proof problems?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to know what I need to know to start solving problems like this, At university Teachers don't explain, So I need to learn on my own, If anyone knows what I need to learn step by step to be able to solve problems like this, I'd be immensely glad.

These examples below is what I need to learn, but I lack some prerequisites to start to learn.

1 - Prove the following statments:

a) If a and b are odd integers, Then 8|(a^2 - b^2).

b) If a and b are any integers, Then a^2 - 4b ≠ 2.

c) Assume 1/a + 1/b is an integer, where a and b are positive integers, show that a = b.

d) The sum of an integer with its cube is even. (Suggestions: a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)^2 - 2ab)

2) Show via finite induction

a) 3|n (7+6n+2n^2)∀ n ∈ N      b) 6|(n^3 - n) ∀ n ∈ N

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic? It'll help with the first two. For the last one, try experimenting with values a bit.

Comment: You don't need to know much except the definitions of the concepts involved ("even," "odd," "integer," "divides"), as well as the meaning of basic statements in logic (e.g. "If A, then B"). The rest is about your reasoning ability.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thanks for your answer, I don't know modular arithmetic, I'll try to learn thanks.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger What modular arithmetic propriety do I need to prove that a^2 - 4b ≠ 2 ?, I studied M.A, and I managed to understand how to prove the first one.

Comment: @Goun2 Note that that's the same as saying $a^2\ne 4b+2$, or $a^2\not\equiv2\pmod4$. Now, $a$ is either $1$ mod 4, $2$ mod 4, $3$ mod 4, or $0$ mod 4; those are the only options. So you can square each of those and see whether any of those become $2$ mod 4.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger How did you get rid of b, You passed 4 to the left hand side, but where is b ? and sorry, Math is my weakness.

Comment: @Goun2 Let's back up a second. You learned modular arithmetic a bit; what is your definition of $x\equiv y\pmod m$?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger both x and y divided by m have the same remainder, and x is congruent to y mod m <=> a - b is divided by m.

Comment: OK. So suppose we had $a^2-4b=2$. We can rearrange that to be $a^2-2=4b$. $~4b$ is a multiple of 4, so that means $a^2-2$ is equal to some multiple of 4. That is, $a^2-2$ is divisible by $4$. Or, in other words, by your definition, $a^2\equiv 2\pmod4$. (So if we have $a^2-4b\ne2$, then this is just the negation, so it's $a^2\not\equiv2\pmod4$.)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thank you so much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I showed your resolution of the $(a^2 - 4b ≠ 2.)$ to my teacher, and He said that was not correct, He said, "Look, 2+3 is divided by 5, but 2 and 3 are not divided by 5". At first I thought He was wrong, then I tried. 39-4/5 is diveded by 5, but 39 and 4 are not, What do you think about it, Is He right or wrong ?

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with anything. Do you agree that it's equivalent to showing that $a^2-2$ is not divisible by 4? Do you agree that that's the same as showing that $a^2\not\equiv2\pmod4$?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger He said that it should work only for this case, but this way you did it has a lot of holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HInt: $a$ is an odd integer $$a=2k+1\\a^2=4k^2+4k+1=\\4\overbrace{k(k+1)}^{even=2q}+1=8q+1$$ 
for a)
$$8|a^2-b^2 \to \\8|(8q_1+1)-(8q_2+1) \checkmark$$ can you go on ?

Comment: I only know the initial concepts of an even and odd number, I searched for the answer for these questions but even with the answer I couldn't understand myself, If you know some important topics to know before dive into examples like this it would help me a lot, anyways thanks for your answer, I'll take the time to understand your answer fully.

Comment: for b) do separation $$a=2k , b=2q+1\\a=2k+1,b=2q+1\\a=2k,b=2q\\a=2k+1,b=2q$$

Comment: I studied some properties of modular arithmetic and your solution for a) makes sense to me, But the b) doesn't, How did you come to that conclusion ?

Comment: @Goun2: Khosrotash's approach for (b) is more complicated than necessary. Suppose for the sake of contradiction there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2-4b=2$. Then $a^2=4b+2=2(2b+1)$. Note that $2(2b+1)$ must be even; hence $a^2$ must be even; hence $a$ must be even. But if $a$ is even, $a^2$ is divisible by 4; hence $2(2b+1)$ is divisible by $4$. This is a contradiction. (Why?)

Comment: @symplectomorphic Sorry , I thought I had gotten the right answer for this question and I ended up ignoring you. But now I need your help. I understand how you proceeded, But I can't understand the reason why a^2 isn't divisble by 4 and a^2 isn't even to confirm that a^2-4b ≠ 2.